# "Can only POST to CGI Scripts" 501 error

Tags: python

I'm running a local CGIHttpServer in Python, and am using this python program to run something in that server:

```
''' submit data to form using robots '''
import urllib
import pprint


# hacking gullible app
url = "http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/w5/captcha.example/vote_app/gullible_app.py"

def vote(lecturer):
    params = urllib.urlencode({'lecturer': lecturer,'submit':'submit'})
    f = urllib.urlopen(url, params)
    pprint.pprint(f.fp.readlines())

vote("Ivo")
```

This tells me it can only POST to CGI scripts, which I find really strange because the python script opens in my web browser at that address just fine. So... it's running in my browser fine, but not when the python program attempts to POST to that URL. What is going on here? (There is VERY little out there on the internet about this - I've tried researching this problem to solve it myself but there's only 3-4 people mentioning this issue)

EDIT: Sorry guys! I did not understand GET and POST. I should have included this in the question - it is the python program "gullible_app.py". As you can see, the form does the "POST" operation

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

# form generation
# -------------------------------------------------------
def print_form():
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    print '''
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="gullible_app.py">
        <p>Select your favorite lecturer:</p>
        <input type="radio" name="lecturer" value="harald" /> Harald
        <input type="radio" name="lecturer" value="ivo" /> Ivo
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
'''

# response generation
# -------------------------------------------------------
def print_response():
    print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
    print '<html><body>Thank you for your vote!</body></html>'

def main():
    user_data = cgi.FieldStorage()
    if "submit" in user_data: # user press "submit"
        lecturer = user_data.getfirst("lecturer")
        f = open( "cgi-bin\\w5\\captcha.example\\vote_app\\votes.txt", "a" )
        f.write( lecturer+'\n' )
        f.close()
        print_response()
    else: # display the form
        print_form()

main()
```

Comment: How did you test it to determine `it's running in my browser fine`? In other words, how are you performing a **POST** operation? Using a browser, I assume you have another page with a form that posts to that URL?

Comment: @WesleyBaugh How I test it is by navigating to http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/w5/captcha.example/vote_app/gullible_app.py, which it renders as per normal

Comment: That doesn't POST though, that does a GET operation.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh oh really? I am only JUST learning about HTTP and web programming

Comment: @WesleyBaugh sorry, I really did not understand the distinction, and realise now I should have included the target program in the original question. The form method that is at gullible_app.py is "POST", I've included it in the original questoin

Comment: Please post the code where you use `CGIHTTPServer` to create the web server, as in this [example](https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/). Have you tried running your script from directly within your `cgi-bin` directory to see if it works like that, without being in a subfolder of `cgi-bin`?

Comment: @WesleyBaugh thanks for the suggestion that it was GET. By fiddling around with things a bit I was able to perform a GET request that was correct

Comment: @WesleyBaugh Oh sorry I didn't see your last comment!!! I can still do that if you wish - however for some reason simply using requests.get instead of urllib.urlopen worked - do you know why that would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side program (which you haven't given so we can't say for sure) only accepts GET requests and not POST requests to the url shown.

urllib makes urlopen act as a POST the way you've done it.  See the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#examples for an example of how to make a request that is a GET

Comment: Hi this made a lot of sense, when I try a get request manually in the browser it works. Oddly enough, when I do what you suggested and send a GET request via urllib (using the EXACT SAME string that works in the web browser) I receive a 404 error, "Nothing matches the given URI". I have even copied and pasted that link into urllib.urlopen('string goes in here') to make sure it was working on the same thing

Comment: Ok I have been able to fix it. Somehow, using the requests module and doing requests.get with the same url solves the issue. I do not know why that happens but it does. Many thanks for the suggestion Vorsprung

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be in the documentation.

Your error message: [`Error 501, “Can only POST to CGI scripts”, is output when trying to POST to a non-CGI url.`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.do_POST)

The big hint: [`run the CGI script, instead of serving it as a file, if it guesses it to be a CGI script`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)

What you need to modify: [`cgi_directories`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories)

So, either put your (Python) CGI script in one of the default sub-directories, or modify the `cgi_directories` to make it "guess" correctly that the URL is supposed to be a CGI script.

Comment: The thing is I have already modified the cgi_directories to include ALL subdirectories of cgi-bin via os.walk, which I thought would have fixed this issue. I did read the docs

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is permission issue. You need to check the permission for cgi script and make it executable.

```
chmod +x <cgi script>
```